# Twitter Api returns Inacurate 24 hour time? Parsing in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, time

I am getting these wacky timestamps from twitter using there api to get a timeline of a specific user.

```
Thu May 31 16:43:37 +0000 2018
```

This time stamp is one for 9:47Am. Yet using traditional parsing methods for 24 hour time provide inaccurate results. What time scale is this and how can I convert that into a regular old 12 hour time , Or timeIntervalSince1970 if possible. Thanks!

This time stamp was obtained from a json response using this:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline

my attempt at parsing this mess:

```
   public func properFormattedTime(with twitterTime : String) -> String{

    let lowerBound = String.Index.init(encodedOffset: 0)
    let upperBound = String.Index.init(encodedOffset: 11)
    let range = lowerBound..<upperBound
    let newStr = String(twitterTime[range])
    print("test \(newStr)")

    let lowerBound1 = String.Index.init(encodedOffset: 11)
    let upperBound1 = String.Index.init(encodedOffset: 13)
    let range1 = lowerBound1..<upperBound1
    let timeStr = String(twitterTime[range1])

    let lowerBound2 = String.Index.init(encodedOffset: 13)
    let upperBound2 = String.Index.init(encodedOffset: 16)
    let range2 = lowerBound2..<upperBound2

    let minsStr = String(twitterTime[range2])

    var timeInt = Int(timeStr)!
    print("test time \(timeInt)")

    if timeInt > 12{
        if timeInt != 24{
        timeInt = timeInt - 12
        }else{
            timeInt = 12
        }
        return "\(newStr) \(timeInt)\(minsStr) PM"
    }else{
        return "\(newStr) \(timeInt)\(minsStr) AM"

    }

}
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide more context. We have no idea how you got this timestamp.

Comment: Show your code used to parse that string into a `Date`.

Comment: And that timestamp is for 9:43:47am if you live in the Pacific timezone.

Comment: I don't see any use of `DateFormatter` in the code you posted.

Comment: see my edit @Alexander

Comment: I couldn't find a dateFormatter to fit this particular string , If you know of one Id love to use it @rmaddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to deal with that date string is to use a `DateFormatter` to first convert the string into a `Date`. Then use another `DateFormatter` to convert into a new string in a desired style.

```
let twitterTimestamp = "Thu May 31 16:43:37 +0000 2018"
let tdf = DateFormatter()
tdf.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
tdf.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
if let date = tdf.date(from: twitterTimestamp) {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateStyle = .medium
    df.timeStyle = .medium
    let result = df.string(from: date)
} else {
    // Unexpected date string
}
```

The result will be in the user's local time.

Set the `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` properties to suit your specific needs.

Comment: See http://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html to get a good understanding of working with dates.